# Follower list or followers list

Tags: grammar

1. Let me check your ‘follower’ list.
2. Let me check your ‘followers’ list.

Follower list or followers list, which one is correct here?

Answer (score 1):

The second one, *Let me check your ‘followers’ list*, is correct.

Using the first one would somehow mean that the list itself is following you.

Answer (score 1):

I’d prefer 2.

If the list is a list of your followers (plural), and as a “list” naturally has a number of entries (plural), then I’d expect the list to be called a “followers list” using the plural.

However, in computer parlance ordinary English usage can be distorted. If your list is really labelled “FOLLOWER“ and not “FOLLOWERS”, on the screen in front of the user, then sentence 1 might be the best alternative.

Why are you using “list” at all? Consider using “Let me check your Followers.”  It should already be clear that “Followers” is a list of users/names. Simpler is often clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It is a "**list of followers**" that means a list of some people who are your followers.

Thus, the correct options is "**a followers list**".